# How to obtain a sentence with a specific word from an array list of sentences?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I'm building an android/Java program which reads from a text file and store each sentence in the text file in an array list. Then it checks the occurrence of a particular word in each sentence and prints out the sentence which contains the word.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.text4);
    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info2);
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("input3.txt")));

        String line;
        List<String> sentences = new ArrayList<String>();


        }

    }

}
```

As you can see from the above code, the program looks for the word "Despite".

My text file consist of three sentences. This program works perfectly by outputting the specific sentence with the word "Despite" if my text file is arranged using the following structure (This structure has a line break after each sentence.

However, if the the text file is arranged in the following structure (No line break after each sentence), the program will output all three sentences on the output screen.

I don't want to add a line break after each of my sentences in the text file for this program to work. How do I alter my code so it works for any type of text file regardless of its structure?

Answer (score 1):

Your `split()` doesn't work, at all. First, your expression will only match this exact substring:

```
.?!\r\n\t
```

Extra tabs at the end are also included in the match.

You probably meant to use a character class, e.g. `[0-9]`, but you forgot the brackets.

Since `line` is exactly one line of text from the file, why are splitting on `\r` and `\n`? Also, why is a tab (`\t`) considered a sentence separator?

Next part that's wrong with the `split()`, is the fact that you're only ever taking the first value (`[0]`). If the split had worked, that would discard the second and third sentences.

Also, when looking for a word, make sure you don't match a longer word, e.g. if looking for `is`, don't match `this`, so you need to include word-boundary checks (`\b`).

To ensure that the matched token, e.g. period, is included in the sentence, you need do use a zero-width positive lookbehind non-capturing group (`(?<=X)`).

Word matching should also be case-insensitive.

And finally, the code structure is wrong. It won't compile since you're missing an end-brace (`}`). This is made extra confusing because of the bad indentations.

Here is updated code:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("input3.txt")))) {

    List<String> sentences = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
        for (String sentence : line.split("(?<=[.?!\t])")) {
            sentence = sentence.trim();
            if (! sentence.isEmpty()) {
                sentences.add(sentence);
            }
        }
    }

    Pattern word = Pattern.compile("\\bDESPITE\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    for (String sentence : sentences) {
        if (word.matcher(sentence).find()) {
            text.setText(sentence);
            break; // No need to continue searching
        }
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error reading file!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems to work but still there is a slight issue. If I put a word such as "some" instead of "Despite", it only displays one sentence which contains the word. As you can see from my text file, the word "some" exist in both first and second sentences. How should I fix this?

Comment: @user5665684 Your code was calling `text.setText()`, so only one value (sentence) could be assigned. Want do you *want* to do, when there's more than one?